# Python - Нужно сделать движение игрока в pygame

Tags: python, pygame

Код:

```
import pygame
import sys
import random
from time import sleep

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)

pygame.init()
pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)



screen = pygame.display.set_mode([900, 900])

pygame.display.set_caption('Gamee')
 
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

background_position = [0, 0]


background_image = pygame.image.load("Фон1сл.png").convert_alpha()
player_image = pygame.image.load("игрок.png").convert_alpha()
player_image.set_colorkey(BLACK)
vrag_image = pygame.image.load("vragn0.png").convert_alpha()
done = False

running = True
speed = 5
x = 50
y = 50
while not done:
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
            running = True

    screen.blit(background_image, background_position)


    playerx = 50

    screen.blit(player_image, [playerx, 750])
    screen.blit(vrag_image, [10, 10])

    pygame.display.flip()


 
    clock.tick(60)
 
pygame.quit()
```

добавте пж скрипт чтобы player_image мог ходить

Comment: Надо сделать - делайте. Будут конкретные вопросы - обращайтесь )

Comment: Мне и надо помочь

Comment: Мне вот на работу нужен человек, который будет делать за меня. Не хотите ли занять эту должность за спасибо от меня в виде слова? И это слово я уже сказал, авансом.

Answer (score -2):

```
import pygame
import sys
import random
from time import sleep

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)

pygame.init()
pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)



screen = pygame.display.set_mode([900, 900])

pygame.display.set_caption('Gamee')
 
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

background_position = [0, 0]

speed = 10

background_image = pygame.image.load("Фон1сл.png").convert_alpha()
player_image = pygame.image.load("игрок.png").convert_alpha()
player_image.set_colorkey(BLACK)
vrag_image = pygame.image.load("vragn0.png").convert_alpha()
done = False

running = True
speed = 5
x = 50
y = 50
while not done:
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
            running = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                x -= speed
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                x += speed
            if event.key == pygame.pygame.K_UP:
                y += speed
            if event.key == pygame.pygame.K_DOWN:
                y -= speed

    screen.blit(background_image, background_position)


    playerx = 50

    screen.blit(player_image, [x, y])
    screen.blit(vrag_image, [10, 10])

    pygame.display.flip()


 
    clock.tick(60)
 
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Danya Спасибо огромное!